# Using ViewFlipper inside TabHost

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I am using TabHost in my application.
When I click on any one of the TabHost, it will display corresponding activity.

What I want is when i swipe on that activity it should display another Activity

I have used a ViewFlipper in the Activity(ChildActivity).
I am using example given [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/ViewFlipper_Animation.aspx)  ....

The problem is : Its displaying the Activity that is loaded initially. Its not flipping the views as i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the code used in the Google I/O scheduler app. It has a class called FlingableTabHost. You would not need a ViewFlipper for this.

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/ScheduleActivity.java

Comment: Link is broken can you provide me a link now?

Comment: hi abhinav have u provide me another link or the source code to over come from this problem..actually i am searching for this issue facing in android ..i think u can solve my problem...thanks u so much in advanse

Answer (score 0):

I would just catch the swipe on the tab's activity and then programmatically change the tab. Dont mess with something inside the tab.

Also, using viewFlippers, maybe you dont needs tabs.

[Android Gestures](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html)
[Swipe Action](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/swipe-action-and-viewflipper-in-android.html)

Comment: Can you please provide me an example related to that ?